# Visual Studio Project Dependency Not working properly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am working on Visual Studio 2022 with Win11 SDK and WIN11 WDK. In one of the solutions, I have one project X which is dependent on another project Y. Now when I am building that solution, X and Y and getting built parallelly, and X is failing even before Y is compiled. I have seen this issue a couple of times, is there any issue with Visual Studio or what? Because I have checked the project dependencies and build order, and everything seems correct. (In the project dependency of X, the checkbox of Y is ticked and in build order also Y comes before X)